# @CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition annotation missing

Tags: java, authentication, java-11

I'm trying to implement a custom authentication module in jee using  java 11 but when I add the annotation **@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition** to configuration class Eclipse complains that the annotation doesn't exists.
Do somebody already had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had the same problem. Reason was I did not have the jar file containing the annotation on my IDE (design time) classpath.